# characterize quotient objects of a ring

Tags: category-theory

We know that the quotient objects of an $A-module$ $R$ are except equivalence, the quotient modules $\frac{R}{S}$ with the homomorphisms $h: R\to \frac{R}{S}$ , $h(r) = r + S$ with $r\in R$.

But characterizing the quotient objects of a ring does not seem to be that simple. It seems to be because in the category of rings the epimorphisms do not coincide with the surjective homomorphisms. My question Can we characterize the quotient objects of a ring??

Comment: Every ring $R$ is itself an $R$ module in a natural way, and quotients of $R$ are the same whether you view it as a ring or a module over itself. The difference lies only in whether you view the kernel as a subobject (which we do when we view it as a sub-$R$-module) or not (we don't when we view it as an ideal of $R$). Can you clarify your question at all?

Comment: Thank you,  is there a quotient object characterization of a ring?

Comment: The quotients of a ring $R$ are exactly the rings $R/I$ with the natural projection $p(r) = r+I$. (cf. the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)))

Comment: There are quotient objects of a ring A not preceding ideals

Comment: I'm misunderstanding your question, then. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Edit the main question, so there is no confusion

Answer (score 4):

You implicitly identify "quotient object" with "epimorphism." It's not at all clear that this is a useful definition. It's right there in the name: a quotient object should be an object given as a *quotient* in some way, and not all epimorphisms have this property. (In other words, "quotient object" is not perfectly categorically dual to "subobject"! Only in very nice categories like abelian categories is that true.)

A useful and general notion of "quotient object" in a category is the following: any morphism $f : a \to b$ has a [kernel pair](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/kernel+pair) $a \times_b a$ (in $\text{Set}$ this computes the equivalence relation on $a$ induced by $f$), and we say that $f$ is an **[effective epimorphism](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/effective+epimorphism)** if $f$ is the coequalizer of its kernel pair (in $\text{Set}$ this computes the quotient by the equivalence relation induced by $f$).

This is a "nonlinear" generalization of "$f$ is the cokernel of its kernel" and you can check that for rings, the effective epimorphisms are precisely the surjections, as follows. If $f : R \to S$ is a morphism its kernel pair is the **[congruence](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/congruence)** (internal equivalence relation)

$$R \times_S R = \{ (r_1, r_2) \in R^2 : f(r_1) = f(r_2) \}$$

which is exactly $\{ (r_1, r_2) \in R^2 : r_1 - r_2 \in I \}$ where $I = \text{ker}(f)$. Now you can check that the coequalizer of the two projections $R \times_S R \rightrightarrows R$ computes the *quotient* $R/I$.

See also [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/regular-and-effective-monomorphisms-and-epimorphisms/). A nice result you can prove is that a morphism is an isomorphism iff it's a monomorphism and an effective epimorphism; note that this is false if "effective" is dropped.

Comment: On the other hand, if you really *do* insist on thinking about epimorphisms of rings, it's a very complicated question: http://www.numdam.org/issues/SAC_1967-1968__2_/

Comment: Right, arbitrary epimorphisms of rings are very complicated. There was an MO question about this for commutative rings awhile back: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like